# how to create json structure in java?

Tags: java, json

```
var abc = {"action":"Remove",        
           "datatable":[
                        {"userid":"userid0","username":"name0"}, 
                        {"userid":"userid1","username":"name1"},               
                        {"userid":"userid2","username":"name2"},           
                        {"userid":"userid3","username":"name3"}                 
                       ]     
           , "msgType":"success"};
```

How could I create above JSON structure in java and send it as response & at client side how could I parse it?

Answer (score 3):

Use Google's [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It converts java objects to and from json.
I've used it and it's really good.

Comment: I can only use json_simple-1.1.jar for JSON library as its being used earlier and I can't add more jar file in lib.Can you provide the code which does the same thing using JSONObject and JSONArray?

Comment: @Ajka It's open source. Why don't you just copy-paste the classes into your project?

Comment: @Ajka If you're already using json-simply, why don't you create the code yoursel? It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

consider groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html (won't help you on the client side though)

Answer (score 0):

Simple as using springframework and mark your @Controller method with @ResponseBody to json-encode your pojos.

Also use @RequestBody to decode json back and if needed use [jackson annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) to customize d/encoding